# Iterate array of dictionary and sort based on key

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, timestamp

[image]I have array of dictionary and the values are as follows:

```
    [["-MXpvzmZdbqzrjND8w9F": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = hi;
    timeStamp = 1617960107264;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}, "-MXq5NAyrkk4ZcvRFM7T": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = "how ru?";
    timeStamp = 1617962828647;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}], ["-MXqa5-pkC28lY_Q_hpZ": {
    lid = "-MWwEpHAhIdhN0i5sltB";
    message = "hi nice cycle";
    timeStamp = 1617971142820;
    title = "Cycle for kids";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}]]
```

Here there are 2 elements in the array. I want to take the last element in both of the array and sort it based on the timestamp value.
How to do it? Please help me.

Comment: Please provide how you represent your example data in Swift.

Comment: this is not javascript.this data is from firebase database.If you observe, there are 2 elements in array.

Comment: var testArray = [[String : Any]]().This is the array of dictionary in which above value is stored.

Comment: Ah... ok, but surely you have some Swift type to represent the values stored in the dictionaries?  Or have you actually been writing code like `(testArray[I][key] as? [String:Any])?["timeStamp"] as? Int`?

Comment: I have not fetched the timestamp yet.Like i said,the array of dictionary has above value with 2 elements in array.The 1st element of array has 2 dictionaries inside and second element has 1 dictionary.Now have to sort these elements based on their timestamp key.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify what I mean: let's say you write let `x = testArray.first!["-MXpvzmZdbqzrjND8w9F"] as! SomeSwiftType`, what would you put for `SomeSwiftType` so that you could actually work with that data? Would it be another `[String; Any]`?

Comment: Then x would be a dictionary which is [String:Any]

Comment: Oh joy.  So this seems like you are starting with a data base, and no Swift data model to go with it.

Comment: This is not from API, so there is no data model for it.The data is from firebase database.

Comment: You should create a model for your objects to make everything easier

Comment: Have added the screenshot of the firebase database.

Comment: let keyvalue = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child("1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3_bPqDIJvYX7g7ZhE8ap0TgeYMYjE2").queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp")
                
                keyvalue.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    
                    if !snapshot.exists() {
                        self.nolistView.isHidden = false
                        return
                        
                    }}

Comment: There are 3 elements in your array... and you already have them ordered by timestamp?

Comment: There are 2 elements only. [["-MXpvzmZdbqzrjND8w9F": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = hi;
    timeStamp = 1617960107264;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}, "-MXq5NAyrkk4ZcvRFM7T": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = "how ru?";
    timeStamp = 1617962828647;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}] This is one element in the array.

Comment: ["-MXqa5-pkC28lY_Q_hpZ": {
    lid = "-MWwEpHAhIdhN0i5sltB";
    message = "hi nice cycle";
    timeStamp = 1617971142820;
    title = "Cycle for kids";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}] this is second element

Comment: It is array of arrays of dictionary

Comment: var testArray = [[String : Any]]() this is the type which is declared.

Comment: The problem is that [key1: value, key2: value] is one dictionary. not an array of dictionaries.

Comment: i agree that is one dictionary and there is one more dictionary

Comment: Which brings up the problem of what the "last element" would mean since a dictionary doesn't have a stable concept of a first or last element except for the trivial case that there is only one element.

Comment: Yes, you have an array that contains two dictionaries.  The first dictionary contains two key-value pairs where the values are another dictionary.

Comment: Yes exactly .now u got the point.so this array has 2 elements.1st element has two dictionaries and second element has one dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that part is clear.  The unclear part is that the elements of the array are dictionaries, not other array.  ... How do we move this to chat?  It would be more efficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231021/discussion-between-saranya-and-chip-jarred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, it seems that that the type of the array is:

```swift
typealias SomeDataArray = [[String: [String: Any]]]
```

So we're missing type safety from the beginning.  The first thing I'd do is define a `struct` to represent `Any` in that definition.  For now I'll just use a `struct` as a wrapper for the inner dictionary, using computed properties for all the fields:

```swift
struct SomeData
{
    let dict: [String: Any]

    var lid: String? { dict["lid"] as? String }
    var message: String? { dict["message"] as? String }
    var timeStamp: Int { dict["timeStamp"] as? Int ?? 0 }
    var title: String? { dict["title"] as? String }
    // Skipping user, because I have no idea what to make of its type.
}
```

Really this should be decoded into some real Swift type, but that's a topic for another day.

So now we redo the `typealias`

```swift
typealias SomeDataArray = [[String: SomeData]]
```

In chat it was explained what within the "last" element for each of these dictionaries can be defined as the one with the largest timeStamp value.  Given that this will give this solution (retaining the keys)

```swift
let results = testData.map {
    dict in dict.map {
        ($0.key, SomeData(dict: $0.value))
    }.sorted { $0.1.timeStamp < $1.1.timeStamp }.last
}.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }.sorted { $0.1.timeStamp < $1.1.timeStamp }
```

If you want to transform it back the `[[String;Any]]` you get from Firebase, then it would be this:

```swift
let results = testData.map {
    dict in dict.map {
        ($0.key, SomeData(dict: $0.value))
    }.sorted { $0.1.timeStamp < $1.1.timeStamp }.last
}.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }.sorted { $0.1.timeStamp < $1.1.timeStamp }
.map { [$0.0: $0.1.dict as Any] }
```